# Can you run both python 2 and python 3?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I currently have python2 installed on my machine. Is it possible to have both python2 and python3 installed on the same machine? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can. You can install any number of Python versions; I have Python 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4 and 3.5 (using [`buildout.python`](https://github.com/collective/buildout.python)).

Comment: Yes, just put them in different directories.

Comment: You might find `virtualenv` useful: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: I'm making the assumption here that you are using windows, in which case the duplicate applies. There is also an [Ubuntu-specific answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/350751/install-and-run-python-3-at-the-same-time-than-python-2).